# CTE/recursive query to split delimited strings only returning one row?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, recursion

I've applied a "borrowed" solution to splitting a delimited string into rows (I'm working in MSSQL 2008 R2), but the solution was specific to CTE/recursive queries. This works great, but only transforms one row of data. How would I adjust this to return all rows in my table (or, better yet, be able to include a where clause)?

I have struck out on researching this for two days, and as I'm not too experienced with CTE/recursive queries or XML...any expertise would be welcome! Thanks!!

```
DECLARE @RowData varchar(2000)
DECLARE @SplitOn varchar(1)
DECLARE @ObjectID int

SELECT 
@ObjectID = ObjectID, @RowData = ObjectName, @SplitOn = ';' from Objects 

declare @xml as xml
SET @XML  = '<t><r>' +  Replace(@RowData , @spliton, '</r><r>') + '</r></t>'  

select @objectid as objectid, rtrim(ltrim(t.r.value('.', 'VARCHAR(8000)'))) as splitvalue
from @xml.nodes('/t/r') as t(r)
```

Comment: what does your data in table look like ?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating a table valued function that does the string splitting like the one found here: http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql.html

Then use an OUTER APPLY to use these against rows in a table.  It is a query, so you can apply a where clause. Here is an example of the create for the function, a temp table that I filled with some test data and the select statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
GO

IF ( OBJECT_ID(N'tmpdb..#Object') IS NOT NULL ) DROP TABLE [#Object];

CREATE TABLE [#Object]
(
  [ObjectId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
, [Object] VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #Object
        ( [Object] )
VALUES  ( 'brad;bill;jerry'), ('Scott;MATT;DEAN'), ('larry;bob;john')

GO

SELECT  [tt].[ObjectId]
      , [s].[Data]
FROM    #Object AS [tt]
        OUTER APPLY dbo.Split([tt].[Object], ';') AS s
WHERE   tt.[ObjectId] < 3
```

Just replace the temp table stuff with your table(s). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not getting more than one row is because you are thinking about sets in a programatic way instead of in a set-centric fashion.

SELECT @ObjectID .... gets one row ... the last row.

I suggest you use CROSS APPLY:

```
-- Data Setup
CREATE TABLE #Objects ( ObjectID INTEGER, ObjectName VARCHAR(2000) )
INSERT INTO #Objects ( ObjectID, ObjectName )
SELECT 1, 'foo;bar' UNION
SELECT 2, 'biz;baz;buz'

-- The Meat and Potatoes. You can add a WHERE to your inner or outer query
SELECT 
  ObjectID,
  RTRIM( LTRIM( t.r.value( '.', 'VARCHAR(8000)' ) ) ) AS splitvalue
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ObjectID,
      CONVERT( XML, '<t><r>' + REPLACE( ObjectName, ';', '</r><r>' ) + '</r></t>' ) AS xml_part
    FROM
      #Objects
  ) AS xml_part_builder
  CROSS APPLY xml_part_builder.xml_part.nodes('/t/r') AS t(r)

-- CLEAN UP
DROP TABLE #Objects
```

Let me know if this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and the explanantion.  I ran into problems with XML because my strings had spaces, but aside from that your solution worked great.

@DB_Brad, I ended up going with your solution (calling a TVF into a query), I appreciate the simplicity of the function your suggested. Like I mentioned above I ran into problems with XML so your solution was a great fit. 

THanks!!